# pth file is not processed

Tags: python, path, pythonpath, pth

I was trying to add some folders to my path, so I added a `.pth` file to my `site-packages` folder. When it didn't work (I printed `sys.path` and it doesn't contain any of the paths I wrote in the file) , I tried to find the `.pth` file from within python and I noticed that the name of one of the folders in the path contains a `.` in it.

Could that be the reason why the `.pth` file wasn't processed? or any other suggestions why Its not working?

I don't think I can change the folder name, it was created when I created a virtual environment, and I think that if I'll change it, it might mess up other things.

The path to the `.pth` is - `home/pomicelltohar/venv/3_6/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pomicell.pth`

`sys.path` is

`['', '/home/pomicelltohar/venv/3_6/lib/python36.zip', '/home/pomicelltohar/venv/3_6/lib/python3.6', '/home/pomicelltohar/venv/3_6/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload', '/home/pomicelltohar/anaconda3/lib/python3.6', '/home/pomicelltohar/venv/3_6/lib/python3.6/site-packages']`

Comment: please add the code that trying to add to `sys.path`

Comment: I didn't write code that tried to add to `sys.path`. python does that automatically if you put the `.pth` file in the  `site-packages` folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that I wrote the paths in the `.pth` file with `~/` instead of using the full path `/home/pomicelltohar`

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced a similar issue where my file contained the correct path but it was not processed. Maybe someone has the same issue. The file was being saved with wierd encoding UTF-16 BOM.

This was the output of powershell:

```
$my_modules_path| Out-File $my_pth_file
```

I could debug this by checking the output file in notepad++, where that enconding was selected instead of the UTF-8 that is now in the photo:

[image: encoding from notepad]

So what i did is saving it with ANSI:

```
$my_modules_path| Out-File -encoding ASCII $my_pth_file
```

Comment: I was using powershell to create the pth file  and this was the solution  !! . After replacing/reencoding the pth file , I cleared the interpreter settings in VsCode before reselecting it ( i.e., my project virtual environment python.exe)